# Select checkbox by class and make the text inside bold

Tags: jquery

After an ajax call, this is how the div is populated with a list of pair (checkbox, name).

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
     $('#userListCheckBox').append(
       '<input type="checkbox" class="cbUser ' + item.IsApproved + 
       '" value="cb_' + item.UserId + '">' +
       item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName + '</input><br/>'
      );
    });
```

Before only approved users could be displayed. Now every user will be displayed. The only difference is that I want to display inactive user in bold. That's why I added the value of the item.IsApproved to the list of classes.

I'm trying to make bold the text inside the checkbox, using the following code.

```
$('#userListCheckBox :checkbox .false').html().css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Checkboxes are self closing and don't "contain" text. You could add a <label> element to it and style that.

Comment: There should be no space between `:checkbox` and `.false` if it's the same element

Comment: `.html()` returns a string. If you want to modify a selected element, you just apply the modification directly to it. Also the HTML you generate is incorrect (as already mentioned).

Comment: there is no `false` class associated with the checkbox

Comment: @ArunPJohny: `item.IsApproved` is probably `false`.

Comment: also you will have to wrap the text next to the input element within a span or another element as text nodes cannot be styled

Comment: something like `$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    $('#userListCheckBox').append(
        '<input type="checkbox" class="cbUser ' + item.IsApproved +
        '" value="cb_' + item.UserId + '" /><span>' + item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName + '</span><br/>');
});
$('#userListCheckBox :checkbox.false').next().css('font-weight', 'bold');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra space in your selector:

```
$('#userListCheckBox :checkbox.false').next("label").css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Also, `input` should be self-closing, you should wrap the text in a `label` and target that.

```
$('#userListCheckBox').append(
   '<label><input type="checkbox" class="cbUser ' + item.IsApproved + 
   '" value="cb_' + item.UserId + '"/>' +
   item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName + '</label><br/>'
  );
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the `for` attribute on label element. I guess we could set an id attribute on checkbox with `item.UserId` value.

Comment: Or put the `input` inside the `label`.

Comment: Edited, put the `input` in the `label`

Comment: Item.IsApproved was producing **False** instead of **false**. Now it's working. Thank you.